# Behind-scene after "umi dev"

Tags: node.js, umijs

Just started learning React js and then I found this enterprise-level react application framework called [Umi](https://github.com/umijs/umi). Since I am just a beginner with Node js too, I am having a hard time understanding what really happened after I typed 'umi dev' in the command line.

I spent some time digging into the source code. My current guess is that somehow umi used another js library called 'webpack-dev-server' to actually run an express server locally. However, I am still confused on how the 'umi dev' command makes all these things happen. Is 'dev' a command? Or is it a class? What should people do if they want a new command like 'umi my-own-command'?

Comment: This seems to be only the 2nd question here about UmiJS, so I think you're unlikely to get an answer. It's worth asking in Umi's support channels directly

Comment: Anyhow, by running `which umi`, you will see the path for the `umi` script, likely it is a JavaScript script which parses its command-line options like "dev" and acts accordingly

Answer (score 0):

`umi` is installed by `yarn global add umi`

i think, you can take a look about `~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/umi`
There's an introduction to `umi`

> there is a file `package.json`
>   directorys `lib`, `bin`, `scripts`. and so on

i hope this helps you